# Prevent Visual Studio from switching tabs to show me warnings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

I'm using [Visual Studio Community for Mac](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/) (2017), which is different from the one on Windows (it's a ["rebranded version of MonoDevelop"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonoDevelop#Visual_Studio_for_Mac)). Specifically, I'm using it to write ASP.NET, C#, JS, and CSS but I think the warnings are only for C# code.

Every time I run my code, I am taken from the tab I was just in to another tab where I have a warning. I find this switching extremely disorienting, so I need it to stop.

I don't need or want to fix the problem causing the warning right now. I know I can go to "Options" > "Compiler", then set "Warnings level" to 0, but I don't want to *not* see a list of the warnings I have.

How can I prevent it from switching my current tab around?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a Community Wiki Entry? Because otherwise it is wierd that you answered the question the same minute you asked it.

Comment: @Christopher It's not "Community Wiki" because neither the question nor the answer are a collaborative effort (nor do I see it being that way in the future). It's all my work, simply because I really wanted an answer to this, so others might too. You should judge the question and answer separately on their own merits, almost as if they were posted by different people. See [Self Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in the Help Center for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After suffering with this for too long, I finally figured out the solution.

Simply check the checkbox next to the error in the list (in the "error pad"):

[image: image of an error that is checked off]

It will be shown (at least at first) in <s>strikethrough</s> and it won't steal your tab focus anymore (unless you uncheck it).

You can either do this for every warning or you can go to Preferences (shortcut: command + comma) and set a setting so that they automatically get checked off. The setting is "Build" > "Jump to first error or warning" and I set it to "Error" since I like being taken to any problem that prevents things from compiling. If you want it to never steal your tab focus, you should set it to "Never".